# No Persistence provider for EntityManager named x

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate

Este meu projeto não reconhece o meu Persistence Provider. Segue o mesmo abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sua localização mais dependências:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou chamando o mesmo através de um XHTML bem simples utilizando um ManageBean. Segue abaixo imagens:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue, por fim, a imagem do erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @Jocsã, experimente tirar o seu `<provider/>` da área de comentário? `<!-- -->` no `persistence.xml`

Comment: @Jocsã tente tirar o persistence.xml de dentro do META-INF, deixa ele apenas dentro de resources. E também tente fazer o que o Marcos sugeriu.

Comment: Ola @renan a versão do hibernate é a mesma do parent, ou seja, dos demais projetos que usamos aqui. Usamos o nexus, e sempre procuramos usar as mesmas versões.

Comment: @MarcosSousa Já deixei sem provider, e também já usei tanto o org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider quanto o org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence e nada.

Comment: @DiegoAugusto já tentei da mesma forma. Inclusive já coloquei dentro da pasta java, mas, sem sucesso. Agradeço a atenção de todos!

Comment: A localização correta é dentro do META-INF do /resources, precisa adicionar o provider ```<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>``` também vi um espaço em branco no valor true em show_sql.

Comment: Essas imagens de código ajudam pouco, ou até prejudicam. Prefira colocar o código mesmo.

Comment: Essa classe está atualizada? Porque no teu log de erro acusa a linha 24 da classe ViewJocsa, mas a linha 24 aí é uma linha em branco. Se estiver, dá um clean no projeto e testa novamente.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, não sei pq deram - na pergunta. Enfim... Irei responder a pergunta.

Comment: @DilneiCunha o persistence estava no local correto, o problema foi outro. Grato!

Comment: @bigown preferências, cada um tem as suas. Grato!

Comment: @GiulianaBezerra consegui resolver o problema e fechei este tópico. Grato!

Comment: Leia isso: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5149/132

Comment: @Jocsã conforme o Victor mostrou não é uma questão de preferência. Dificulta muito o trabalho de quem quer te ajudar. Já que está pedindo ajuda poderia fazer a gentileza de facilitar o trabalho dessa pessoa que não está ganhando nada e não tem obrigação alguma.

Answer (score 3):

O problema era simples! O código estava correto...

Houve problema pois o  no meu pom.xml explicitou para que as dependências fossem provider. Ou seja, na hora de subir ao servidor, o war ia sem as dependências.

Para resolver o problema, passei a usar um servidor com as libs do projeto já dentro da pasta lib do próprio servidor e isso resolveu o problema. Poderia também usar um atributo específico (que agora não lembro o nome) para poder forçar que gerasse o war com as dependências, mas não foi o caso já que o padrão aqui do setor é deixar as libs no próprio servidor.

Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos!